# How to write api test case for generic class based views in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here i am writing some api test case for some create,update views and i tried like this.But this is giving me error.What i might be doing wrong?Is there any solution for this?

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 403 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.031s

FAILED (failures=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', ProductCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create-product'),
    path('list/', ProductListAPIView.as_view(), name='list-product'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='detail-product'),
]
```

views.py

```
class ProductCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
class ProductListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'description', 'category']
class ProductDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

tests.py

```
CREATE_PRODUCT_URL = reverse('product:create-product')
LIST_PRODUCT_URL = reverse('product:list-product')
class CreateProductTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
    def test_details(self):
        response = self.client.post(CREATE_PRODUCT_URL,format='json')
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
class ListProductTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
    def test_details(self):
        response = self.client.get(LIST_PRODUCT_URL,format='json')
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting 403 code because all of your views are permitted only to superusers because of the `IsAdminUser` permission.

You need to make your tests by logging in as admin user. You can use `login` method of `Client()` to do that.

And for your Create test method you need to provide a valid Product in your input as you want test a view that is supposed to create a product.

Here is a sample test case for your `CreateProductTest` and `ListProductTest`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework import status


CREATE_PRODUCT_URL = reverse('product:create-product')
LIST_PRODUCT_URL = reverse('product:list-product')


class CreateProductTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
                "admintest",
                "admintest@admintest.com",
                "admintest"
            )
        self.client.login(username='admintest', password='admintest')

    def test_details(self):
        payload = {
            'product_key1', 'product_value1',
            'product_key2', 'product_value2',
            # ...
        }
        response = self.client.post(CREATE_PRODUCT_URL, payload)
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class ListProductTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
                "admintest",
                "admintest@admintest.com",
                "admintest"
            )
        self.client.login(username='admintest', password='admintest')

    def test_details(self):
        response = self.client.get(LIST_PRODUCT_URL,format='json')
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: That is completely because of another issue, which is you do not provide a valid Product JSON input in your create request. I've edited my answer to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow

1. create user in `setUp` method
2. authenticate user in `test_<method>`
3. send request to url with data

```
CREATE_PRODUCT_URL = reverse('product:create-product')

class CreateProductTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User(username="testuser", email="testemail@test.com")
        self.user.is_staff = True
        self.user.set_password('secret')
        self.user.save()

    def test_details(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username="testuser", password="secret"))
        post_data = {} # your data here in dict
        response = self.client.post(CREATE_PRODUCT_URL, post_data, format='json')
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```